# Estimate half of the sum of binomial

Tags: binomial-distribution

I know that the following sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n} C_{n}^{i} \cdot (1-p)^i \cdot p^{n-i}$ is equal to 1. It is also not hard (but tedious) for me to calculate

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2} C_{n}^{i} \cdot (1-p)^i \cdot p^{n-i}$$

where $n$ is the odd number and $p > 0.5$. Just to make sure I wrote the formula correct, here is an example of what I want to calculate for n=5 and p=0.7:

$$C_{5}^{0} \cdot 0.7^5 \cdot 0.3^0 + C_{5}^{1} \cdot 0.7^4 \cdot 0.3^1 + C_{5}^{2} \cdot 0.7^3 \cdot 0.3^2$$

I am almost sure that there is an easy way to estimate this sum (for a big number of $n$), but I can't find it.

Comment: For big $n$ (which $n = 5$ most certainly isn't, of course), one can use the normal approximation.  How accurate it is depends on the values of $n$ and $p$.

Comment: I guess $C_{n}^{i} = {n \choose i}$. Right ?.

Comment: For large $n$, the general term can be approximated by a Gaussian
$$
\propto \exp\left(\,-\,{\left\{\, i - n\left[\,1 - p\,\right]  \,\right\}^{2} \over 2n\left[1-p\right]p} \, \right)
$$

Comment: @FelixMarin sorry for a late reply. Yes, this is binomial coefficient